# Can't get JSON Data from external URL in PHP

Tags: php, json, curl, decode

Here is the url from where i am trying to get the JSON data but i am unable to get it on the other site, it returns blank, nothing.

Here is the code i am using to try to decode

```
$url = 'http://habbolicense.epizy.com/verify?url=https://ujimaradio.com&key=05c99851c3f982a4e2fc874846308594';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$obj = json_decode($result);
echo 'result = '.$obj->access_token;
```

Here is the URL: http://habbolicense.epizy.com/verify?url=https://ujimaradio.com&key=05c99851c3f982a4e2fc874846308594

Thank You

Comment: What does `$result` look like? Do you get any help from `curl_error($ch)`?

Comment: Tried that, still blank

Comment: Even when i return $result . It returns blank

Comment: I don't get an empty $result. Here's a trucated portion of it:
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var

Comment: @MichaelRuth how did you get that from $result ? I was trying to echo it and found nothing

Comment: @UsmanMalik, I just echoed $result after the curl_exec, i.e. $result = curl_exec($ch); echo $result;

Answer (score 0):

The URL uses javascript to produce content, specifically `{"access_token": "KeyFound"}`. This means that the client must understand javascript in order to render the page. This can be seen in the full response:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script>
    <script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("7b0167f2554521ca32df18773a2853a1");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="http://habbolicense.epizy.com/verify?url=https://ujimaradio.com&key=05c99851c3f982a4e2fc874846308594&i=1";</script>
    <noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can't do this with cURL, in fact, you can't do this with basic HTTP request libraries, this task requires the ability to execute javascript. This *can* be done using a headless browser, but there aren't many options in PHP, [php-phantomjs](https://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/) is one and [headless-chromium-php](https://github.com/chrome-php/headless-chromium-php) is another. Note that php-phantomjs is just a wrapper around [PhantomJS](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs). There are many more options if you're not limited to PHP. This is where javascript-based solutions are going to shine since what you need is something that can execute javascript.

Here is a [list of headless browsers](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers) that includes a little info about their capabilities and limitations.